# Is it possible to upload Image to a website from Safari on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to upload a photo from my iPhone to a website. However, the browse button to display the select file dialog is disabled. Normally this works fine on my HTC Mobile and all Android Mobiles. Should I be able to select image files to upload from Safari on iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

This is not available prior to iOS 6. Since iOS 6, the select file button will open the typical select from library / take photo or video view.

Answer (score 0):

I checked some website and it seem to only allow you to upload files that is stored inside the Photo Library (I am running iOS 6 for this). The thing with iOS is that there is no file system type behaviour that you normally find on a Windows and Android environment. Hence that explains why you can do it on your HTC but not on your iPhone.

If you need more information, this [blog here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/13/ios-6-safari-media-uploads/) explains how iOS 6 handles file upload.